# Send Email and Reply to System

Tags: c#

My client is using web form to send mail to his clients. It is C# code and works fine. He want to keep history of all mails sent and reply against that mail.
I am using a database where each mail sent from web form is saved. So we can get email sent history. But how can i get reply history.
He wants feature like it is in elance. Where user reply through his email address but that emails also appears in Elance inbox.
Please help me what should i need/study for it

thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you storing the e-mails by an ID other than something the user entered? If not, start doing that. I'll assume you're using numbers, but you could use any other form of identification.
2. For every e-mail you store a reply to number, with default null, because most e-mails are not a reply.
3. This reply number is an inner reference to another e-mail.
4. When accessing an e-mail you check if there is a reply number stored.
5. If so retrieve that e-mail as well and show it, keep checking until the retrieved e-mail has null for a reply number.

Edit: I assumed you where already storing all e-mails and just needed to link them together. But it seems you will have to add a feature to his e-mail client that stores sent e-mails. Or put a listener on the network that will store any passing e-mails. Or you can add a feature to the system to read the e-mails that where sent from the web forms and allow replying. This custom e-mail client will also store all the replies.